# Proof of an Inequality with exponents

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

I have been given a function $$f(a, b, c) = (a^{b+c-2a})(b^{a+c-2b})(c^{a+b-2c})$$ and I need to prove that $$f(a, b, c) \le 1$$ $\mathbf{Case 1:}$ If $a=b=c$, then it is trivial that $f(a,b,c)=1$. But now, I am stuck with how to prove for $f(a,b,c)<1$? Is the further proof related to AM or GM in some way? $(a,b,c > 0)$

EDIT 1: $$log((a^{b+c-2a})(b^{a+c-2b})(c^{a+b-2c})) = ((b+c-2a)log(a))+((a+c-2b)log(b))+((a+b-2c)log(c))$$

$$a(log(bc))+b(log(ac))+c(log(ab))-2(log(a^ab^bc^c)) \le 1$$

EDIT 2: The original problem in the [book](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Pathfinder_to_Olympiad_Mathematics_1e/1oqqDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Pathfinder%20for%20Olympiad%20and%20JEE%20(Advanced)%20Mathematics&printsec=frontcover) I was practicing from  was to prove that $a^{(b+c)}b^{(a+c)}c^{(a+b)}\le(a^ab^bc^c)^2$. I arrived at $f(a, b, c)$ through simplification.

EDIT 3: Assuming $a \ge b \ge c$ without loss of generality, this implies that $k^{b+c} \le k^{2a}$ and similarly for other terms (if $k \in$ {$a,b,c$}, k>1 since a, b, c are positive reals). Thanks to [Calvin Lin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/54563/calvin-lin) for suggesting Chebyshev.

Comment: Can you flesh out your solution more? It's not clear to me what you're doing. For example, $ k ^ {b + c } > k^{2a}$ is only true if $ k > 1$, and note that conversely we have $k ^{a+b} > k^{2c}$ also if $ k > 1$.

Comment: Do you mean, $k \ge 1$? Because if that's the case then it was given that $a,b,c > 0$.

Comment: To be explicit, 1) I do not know what you're doing in edit 3. 2) For example, with $ a = 0.5, b = 0.25, c = 0.25$, $a^{b+c - 2a} \geq 1 $. 3) Like you said, we are only given that $ a, b, c, > 0$, but you seem to have assumed that $ a, b, c \geq 1$.  \( \quad \) Given all this, please write out what you intended in Edit 3 fully, in order to properly continue this discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that $ a^b b^c c^a \leq a^a b^b c^c$.

Comment: I am not able to proceed any further. The hint didn't work. Could you please tell me the appropriate method to proceed?

Comment: @AyaanMaan Take logarithm and apply Chebyshev. If you're stuck, explain what you have tried (even if it didn't work).

Comment: Doesn't this require also to prove $a^cb^ac^b<a^ab^bc^c$?

Comment: @BookOfFlames Of course, which is again the hint. Should I write the hint again?

Comment: No, if the OP is able to get to the point where (s)he is able to recognize the need to prove one of the above hints, it's also enough to recognize the significance to prove the other hint.

Comment: @AyaanMaan A) Not quite, the powers don't need to be equal. E.g. can you simplify / rewrite $ \log 2^2 3^3 $ ? B) That's the "other" chebyshev inequalty.  See [this](https://brilliant.org/wiki/chebyshev-inequality/).

Comment: $2(log2)+3(log3)$

Comment: @AyaanMaan Great, so what's log of the LHS and RHS? Can you apply Chebyshev to show that it is true?

Comment: Aready did @CalvinLin. See edits.